# Вложенный запрос SQL или выборка из выборки

Tags: php, sql

Доброго времени суток.
Есть БД с 3мя таблицами(values,properties,products, был написан такой запрос:

```
$test = R::getAll('SELECT DISTINCT products.name, color.value, size.value FROM products 
  JOIN `values` AS color ON color.products_id = products.id
  JOIN `values` AS new ON new.products_id = products.id
  JOIN `values` AS size ON size.products_id = products.id
  JOIN `values` AS v ON v.products_id = products.id
  WHERE 
     new.properties_id = 3 AND new.value = 1
      AND
     color.properties_id = 2 AND color.value = "GREEN"
     AND
     size.properties_id = 1');
```

Но он работает не так, как хотелось бы, то есть он выводит только размер в итоге, такого вида

```
array(6) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(33) "Предмет 1"
    ["value"]=>
    string(3) "XXL"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(10) "Предмет 3"
    ["value"]=>
    string(3) "XXL"
  }
```

а цвет не выводит ( ну или наоборот, если поменять в запросе в SELECT местами color.value и size.value)
подскажите, как сделать выборку так, чтобы выводилось в итоге:
имя, цвет, размер?
 Думал о вложенных запросах, но я с ними так и не разобрался, так как либо у меня ошибку выдаёт при попытке вместо последних AND вписать вложенный запрос, либо выдаёт пустой массив, но так или иначе, я не понимаю почему не выводится то, что нужно.

По сути, наверное, мне нужна просто выборка из выборки... сначала выбрать всё где new.value = 1, а из полученного массива, выбрать всё где color.value = "GREEN", но реализовать её я так и не смог, так как не понимаю как обратиться к полям, которые не выводятся в итоге после первой выборки.

Comment: дайте им псевдонимы `color.value color_value , size.value size_value`

Comment: Господи, да это работает! спасибо огромное, но как алиасы на это повлияли? поясните? (не могу отметить как ответ, так как вы ответили в комментариях)

Comment: у вас получалось два поля с одинаковым именем value, один перезаписывал второй. Когда вы задали псевдонимы, php начал получать их как два разных элемента массива

Comment: Спасибо огромное, я думал задать алиасы в запросе JOIN было достаточно, а про SELECT забыл совсем.. да и изначально там вообще было * или products.* =) очень вам благодарен